# How to forward port 80 to 80 on vagrant homestead

Tags: laravel, nginx, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I am using vagrant and homestead for my laravel project.

I have to write myapp.dev:8000 every time to access the app and this makes it hard to test oauth with nonstandard port.

Is there a way by which I only need to write myapp.dev to access the app. I have tried to fwd port 80 to 80 and tried to access app but it give some nginx error.

Comment: if you have nothing running on port 80 from your host, it will work - you have error in you have apache/nginx running on your host

Comment: If you don't give details on the error you are receiving no one will be able to help you

Comment: hmmm solved it, i was using 127.0.0,1 instead of 192.168.10.10 in hosts file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `php artisan` serve you can pass the flag `--host=0.0.0.0` and `-port=80` to broadcast to all avalible network cards and on port 80. You can omit the host flag if you dont need it.

```
php artisan serve --port=80 --host=0.0.0.0
```